# Hide EOL character in EMACS

Tags: emacs

I enabled whitespace in Emacs 24.4, and I like everything, except the EOL `$` character showing. How can I hide it?

I know I can change it's color with

```
'(whitespace-newline ((t (:foreground "red" :background "nil"))))
```

but how can I make the foreground and the background **match** my theme, without setting the exact colors. Is there something like "transparent" on "invisible"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you should customize the `whitespace-style` variable and simply remove the newline options.